# Modify AWS ALB traffic distribution using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-elb

I have an AWS ALB with a listener configured where default action is to **forward** traffic in active-active mode : 50% of traffic to a target group (`TargetGroupA`) and 50% to another target group (`TargetGroupB`).

To perfom maintenance, I would like to edit this rule using AWS CLI to :

- change the traffic distribution percentage from 50-50 to 100% on `TargetGroupA`
- change the traffic distribution percentage from 100% on `TargetGroupA` to 100% on `TargetGroupB`
- Put back the 50-50 on both target groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should use [modify-listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-listener.html).

The `--default-actions` parameter has a `ForwardConfig.TargetGroups.Weight` setting that ranges from 0 to 999.

Use weights like `1,0`, `1,1` (50% each) and `0,1` to direct traffic to the target groups.

Answer (score 2):

Using the link given by @john-rotenstein, this command worked for me (with `aws-cli/1.18.37`):

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener \
--listener-arn "<listener arn>" \
--default-actions \ 
  '[{
      "Type": "forward",
      "Order": 1,
      "ForwardConfig": {
        "TargetGroups": [
            {"TargetGroupArn": "<target group 1 arn>", "Weight": 1 },
            {"TargetGroupArn": "<target group 2 arn>", "Weight": 0 }
        ]
      }
   }]'
```